# Web browser invincible pop up with react or?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I want to add pop up to my app. But an invincible pop up.
What i mean is, pop should alert user no matter where he at- desktop, other software or page.

Maybe something like gmail pop ups on dekstop ?

How it is done ?

Is is even possible ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for...

[Creating a Browser Notification in JavaScript](https://attacomsian.com/blog/desktop-notifications-javascript)

I don't know `React.js` or enough `Python` so I hope this is enough!

Please tell me if this is not what you are looking for!

Comment: Yes, it is! Therm to look for is descktop notification.
For react could be: https://github.com/leejaen/React-Desktop-Notification